# Can I create a device context that is just a portion of another device context?

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I have subclassed a graphics control that takes a device context handle, HDC, as an input and uses that for drawing. My new control is just the original control centered on top of a larger image. I would like to be able to call the original control's Draw() method for code re-use, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Here's the idea:

```
void CCheckBox::DrawCtrl( HDC hdc, HDC hdcTmp, LPSIZE pCtlSize, BYTE alpha ) {
    // original method draws a checkbox
}

void CBorderedCheckBox::DrawCtrl( HDC hdc, HDC hdcTmp, LPSIZE pCtlSize, BYTE alpha ) {
    // Draw my image here
    // Create new hdc2 and hdcTemp2 which are just some portion of hdc and hdcTemp
    //   For example, hdc2 may just be a rectangle inside of hdc that is 20 pixels 
    //   indented on all sides.
    // Call CCheckBox::DrawCtrl() with hdc2 and hdcTemp2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confused of what a device context is. A device context is a place in memory that you can draw to, be it the screen buffer or a bitmap or something else. Since I imagine you only want to draw on the screen, you only need one DC. To accomplish what you want, I would recommend passing a rectangle to the function that tells it where to draw. Optionally, and with poorer performance, you could create a new Bitmap for the smaller area, and give the function the Bitmap's DC to draw on. Now that I think about it, that might have been what you meant in the first place :P Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While not foolproof, you can fake a DC as a subsection of a DC by using a combination of [SetViewportOrgEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145099%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SelectObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with a region clipped to the sub area in question.

The problem with this approach is if drawing code already uses these APIs it needs to rewritten to be aware that it needs to combine its masking and offsetting with the existing offsets and clipping regions.